# H2 database login issues

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm

I am using a local file based H2 Hibernate database with Grails.

I have two separate file type dBs setup in dataSource.groovy:

```
 dataSource {
    logSql = false
    pooled = true
    dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
    url = "jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
}
```

and

```
dataSource_publish {
    logSql = false
    pooled = true
    dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
    url = "jdbc:h2:/dbmak/devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
}
```

They both produce files in the project root directory:

> devDb.h2.db and dbmak.h2.db

The last thing I did in the dB was to modify the 'sa' password - preferring to set it to a non-null value.

I did this by logging into the  dbconsole via user 'sa' and then using the command:

```
set password 'newPassword'
```

Which seemed to work fine.

However, when I now try and restart the application in the GGTS I get the error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-173]
```

I've tried the original null password as well as other login/password combinations that have worked in the past but still get the above error.

One other thing I've done is to replace the h2.db files with recent backed-up copies but still no success. I was wondering if the hibernate system data, containg the 'sa' password, resides elsewhere rather than these individual application databases. If I have a copy of the h2.db files when the system worked I can simply replace it with the modified one that is now failing.

One more thing - when I compare the size of the current (failing - which is 230kb in size) debdb.h2.db file with the backed-up one (which is 1252kb in size) I notice that they are significantly different in size, and when I try and restart the application with the backed-up copy of the db file. After the application fails to start the size goes back to failed size of 230kb.

Comment: I am still unable to login to this dB. Perhaps someone can give me further information how this hibernate db is structured especially in terms of where it retains system user data. As stated above the two application dBs are situated in the root directory of the grails application and I imagine that the actual hibernate system data controls access to both individual application dBs in the hibernate dB structure is going to be in a separate file. If I could locate this I might be able to resolve this problem? Alternatively, if there is a web link to this?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this login issue - as I have two separate Dbs and having set the sa both passwords to a non-null value I have to explicitly define the password for each separate Db.

So, in the DataSource.groovy I now have two sets of login/ password definitions:

```
dataSource {
username = "sa"

password = "value01"
```

}

dataSource_publish {

```
username = "sa"
password = "value02"
```

}

Without this I believe the login & password is automatically set to 'sa' and "" (i.e: null). And so without the dataSource_publish block on startup the app was attempting, unsuccessfully, to login into the dataSource_publish dB with a null password.

Once you see it it's obvious.